# Angular2 opening ngx-modal without a button click

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I will preface by saying I am very new to Angular2. I need to find a way to open an alert Modal with a failed login, code commented below "//failed login", all examples I find rely on a button click, is there a way to do this based on the state of a Boolean value?

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { UsersService } from '../users.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-modal';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent {
  constructor(private usersService: UsersService, private router: Router) {}

  user: string;
  pass: string;
  liwr: boolean = false;


  loginPressed(username, password){
  console.log(username + " " + password);


    this.usersService.loginAttempt(username, password).subscribe(response => {
   console.log(response[1]);

      //admin login
   if (response[0].status === 'success' && response[1].userInfo.privilegeStatus === 'admin'){

    this.router.navigateByUrl('/posts');
        this.usersService.authStatus = response[1].isAuth;
        this.usersService.userSessionObj = response[1];

      //staff login
      } else if (response[0].status === 'success' && response[1].userInfo.privilegeStatus === 'staff'){

        this.router.navigateByUrl('/staff');
        this.usersService.authStatus = response[1].isAuth;
        this.usersService.userSessionObj = response[1];

      //failed login
      } else if (response[0].status === 'invalid'){

        this.liwr = true;
        console.log(this.liwr);

      }

  });
  }
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <button (click)="myModal.open()">open my modal</button>
    <modal #myModal>
        <modal-header>
            <h1>Modal header</h1>
        </modal-header>
        <modal-content>
            Hello Modal!
        </modal-content>
        <modal-footer>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="myModal.close()">close</button>
        </modal-footer>
    </modal>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `ViewChild` :

```
import {ViewChild}  from '@angular/core';

export class LoginComponent {
  @ViewChild('myModal') modal: any;
  constructor() { }

  /...
  else if (response[0].status === 'invalid'){
        this.modal.open();
        this.liwr = true;
        console.log(this.liwr);

  }

 /...

}
```

Comment: Thank you sir! Works great.